# Rewrite dynamic substring in URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

As the title suggests, my goal is to add a rewrite statement in `.htaccess` to replace a dynamic substring in the middle of a URL. Additionally, I need all occurrences of "|" to be changed to "+".

For instance, I'd like to take this URL

```
www.domain.com/?t=p&c=some+string&skus=string1|string2|string3
```

And redirect it to:

```
www.domain.com/?q=string1+string2+string3
```

Basically, the substring to replace starts at "t=" and ends at "skus".

Is this possible? Is this easier to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)** function

this would do the trick

```
$url = "www.domain.com/?t=p&c=some+string&skus=string1|string2|string3";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($decoded = parse_url($url));
print_r($parsed = queryToArray($decoded['query']));
$parms = explode("|", $parsed['skus']); 
print_r($parms);
echo "</pre>";


function queryToArray($qry)
{
    $result = array();
    //string must contain at least one = and cannot be in first position
    if(strpos($qry,'=')) {

     if(strpos($qry,'?')!==false) {
       $q = parse_url($qry);
       $qry = $q['query'];
      }
    }else {
            return false;
    }

    foreach (explode('&', $qry) as $couple) {
            list ($key, $val) = explode('=', $couple);
            $result[$key] = $val;
    }
    return empty($result) ? false : $result;
}

the result should look like this

    Array
(
    [path] => www.domain.com/
    [query] => t=p&c=some+string&skus=string1|string2|string3
)
Array
(
    [t] => p
    [c] => some+string
    [skus] => string1|string2|string3
)
Array
(
    [0] => string1
    [1] => string2
    [2] => string3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP built-in function when possible. So in this case use parse_url and parse_str.

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
$params = explode('|', $query['skus']);
```